# Show that using Suffix Notation

Tags: tensors, fluid-dynamics, index-notation

I'm not sure what this would be in Suffix notation:
$$\mathbf{Tr}\left[\left(\underline{\nabla}\,\underline{u}\right)^2\right]$$
I've got that:
$$\left[\underline{\nabla}\,\underline{u}\right]_i=\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$$
So then would the square be:
$$\left[\left(\underline{\nabla}\,\underline{u}\right)^2\right]_i=\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$$
Finally leading to:
$$\mathbf{Tr}\left[\left(\underline{\nabla}\,\underline{u}\right)^2\right]_i = \left[\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_j}\right]_{jk}$$
Am I wrong? I'm not very sure on the final line on how a trace will change the suffix notation.

Comment: Your third equation makes no sense - on the RHS you have a scalar (since all indices are paired), but you have a free index on the LHS. The scalar you have on the right is what we would normally call $|\nabla u|^2;$ whereas $(\nabla u)^2$ refers to the matrix product $\nabla u \, \nabla u$.

Comment: oh then I'm lost. I thought what I said was $\nabla u \nabla u$

Comment: oh wait would the RHS be $$\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$$ @AnthonyCarapetis

Comment: @M.Turner: No. Your problem starts in the second formula: $\nabla u$ is a matrix, so you must write $(\nabla u)_{ij} = \partial u_i/\partial x_j$. Id notation $\nabla u$ doesn't like you, consider a matrix $A$ such that the $(i,j)-th$ element is $\partial u_i/\partial x_j$. Then compute the matrix $A^2$ and its trace.

Comment: I think that $$A^2=\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$$ and the trace is the sum of the diagonal so when $j=i$ are the same. So that would be $$\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_i}$$ but that would be $\left(\nabla \cdot \underline{u}\right)^2$? I'm just so confused with all of this :( @Dog_69

Comment: No. $A^2$ is the matrix product $A\cdot A$, so its general $(i,j)$-th term is given by the formula $$(A\cdot B)_{ij} \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} b_{kj}$$. In this case $A=B$ and thus $$(A^2)_{ij}= \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{kj} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_k} \frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_j} $$. Now you are right. The trace is the contraction of indices $i$ and $j$, so, finally $$\mbox{tr } A^2 = \sum_{i,k=1}^n  \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_k} \frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_i} $$.